# Laplace transform of $f(t)=2^t+\theta(t-1)\cos(t-1)$

Tags: laplace-transform

I want to find the Laplace transform for this

$f(t)=2^t+\theta(t-1)\cos(t-1)$

The first part is easy:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty 2^te^{-st}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{t\ln2}e^{-st}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{t(\ln2-s)}dt=\bigg [\frac{1}{\ln2-s}e^{t(\ln2-s)}\bigg]_0^\infty=-\frac{1}{\ln2-s}
\end{equation}

But the second, seems more tricky.  Since the unit step function of this interval (t-1) is 0 for all  $t<1$, we can readily form the given integral which is zero:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 0\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt=0
\end{equation}

but

Solve

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty 1\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty \cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt
\end{equation}

But when trying integration by parts, we get:

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt=-\frac{cos(t-1)}{s}e^{-st}-\frac{1}{s}\int_1^\infty\sin(t-1)e^{-st}dt
\end{equation}

or we get

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt=sin(t-1)e^{-st}+s\int_1^\infty\sin(t-1)e^{-st}dt
\end{equation}

Doing an integration on the last term of the latter, gives:

\begin{equation}
s\int_1^\infty\sin(t-1)e^{-st}dt=-\sin(t-1)e^{-st}+\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt
\end{equation}

Inserting this in the original integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt=sin(t-1)e^{-st}+\sin(t-1)e^{-st}-\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt
\end{equation}

which gives:

\begin{equation}
2\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt=sin(t-1)e^{-st}+\sin(t-1)e^{-st}
\end{equation}

finally

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt=\frac{1}{2}\big(sin(t-1)e^{-st}+\sin(t-1)e^{-st}\big)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt=sin(t-1)e^{-st}
\end{equation}

Thus:

The Laplace transform is

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}\{2^t+\theta(t-1)\cos(t-1)\}=-\frac{1}{\ln2-s}+sin(t-1)e^{-st}
\end{equation}

UPDATE

Using the second approach on that second term:

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)e^{-st}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty(e^{iu}-e^{-iu})e^{-s(u+1)}du
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty(e^{iu}-e^{-iu})e^{-s(u+1)}du=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{iu-s(u+1)}-e^{-iu-s(u+1)}du
\end{equation}

Take the former of the last two integrals

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{iu-s(u+1)}du=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{e^{iu-s(u+1)}}{i-s}\bigg]_0^\infty
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{e^{iu-s(u+1)}}{i-s}\bigg]_0^\infty=\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{e^{iu-s(u+1)}}{i-s}\bigg]-\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{e^{iu-s(u+1)}}{i-s}\bigg]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{-s}}{i-s}
\end{equation}

Take the latter of the two integrals,

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-iu-s(u+1)}du=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{e^{-iu-s(u+1)}}{-i-s}\bigg]_0^\infty
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{e^{-iu-s(u+1)}}{-i-s}\bigg]_0^\infty=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}\bigg[\frac{e^{-iu-s(u+1)}}{-i-s}\bigg]-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\bigg[\frac{e^{-iu-s(u+1)}}{-i-s}\bigg]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{-s}}{-i-s}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}\{2^t+\theta(t-1)\cos(t-1)\}=-\frac{1}{\ln2-s}-\frac{e^{-s}}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{i-s}+\frac{1}{-i-s}\bigg)
\end{equation}

but this differs from the correct answer found by integration by parts

Comment: $\int\cos(t-1)\,dt = \frac{1}{t-1}\sin(t-1)$ is incorrect.  To compute the Laplace transform, you to not need to do $\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)\,dt$, which diverges.  You need to do $\int_1^\infty\cos(t-1)e^{-st}\,dt$

Comment: Indeed, I forgot compeltely

Comment: @GEdgar I tried to solve this integral, but it is still difficult. There are two major problems, the limits are not the usual Laplace transform limits, $1 \rightarrow \infty$, so I don't know if a Laplace table is valid, since Laplace tables correspond to the limit$0 \rightarrow \infty$. Then, ignoring this,  I tried to solve it by replacing $cos(t-1)=cosu=1/2( e^{iu}-e^{-iu})$, and $u$ being $(t-1)$. But this does not work either. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks Moo. Will give that a try.

Comment: @Moo see my attempt in the original post

Comment: Now, do it a second time and see if you can spot the pattern.

Comment: @Moo, OK, I did, got 0.... seems strange...but what do you think?

Comment: Can't get that result  at all, I get zero either way I try

Comment: You should simplify things with $u=t-1$. It's an instructive exercise to solve this with complex numbers viz. $\cos u=\Re\exp(iu)$, even after you've understood where your original approach malfunctioned.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for that interesting input. I will give it a try and make an update

Comment: In the equation after "or we get", there should be a plus sign at the start of the right side and in front of the integral, not a minus sign (maybe you added an extra minus when calculating the antiderivative of $\cos(1-t)$).

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! I will give it a go with the u version too

Comment: @J.G. Tried your suggestion.

Comment: I've read your edit. You've got the right idea, except for a miscalculation. If $\Re z>0$,$$\int_0^\infty e^{-zs}ds=\left[-\frac1ze^{-zs}\right]_0^\infty=\frac1z.$$You appear to have consistently treated the $\infty$ integral limit correctly, but not the $0$ one.

Comment: @J.G. You are right, I edited it now. But I used a regular integration of u as a real variable, not as a complex variable. This is also what you did, but you used z, instead of u.  Let me know how it is now, the new edit. Thanks!

Comment: Your recent edits keep writing $1-s$ when you should have a different denominator, but I think you should be able to fix it.

Comment: Yes, it is i-s . It is corrected already. But the form you have at the end, is it equivalent to the sine-form on the first method? To me it seems incorrect, because it gives the wrong Taylor expansion. see here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7B-s%7D%7D%7B2%7D%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bi-s%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B-i-s%7D%29

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannot comment in the comment section. What if you write $cos(t-1)=cos(t)cos(1)+sin(t)sin(1)$ and then use the polar form of the trigonometric functions? After distributions, you will get everything in terms of constants, exponentials, and products of the form $e^{at}t$, for suitable $a$ and for all of them you should have explicit formulas (remember that the exponential just moves the argument of the Laplace transform.

Usually in this kind of problems is not necessary to solve the integral, but rather play a little bit with the properties before getting something that can be computed using the standard Laplace table.

I hope this helps!